# Tensorflow Warning while saving SparseTensor

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working on a TensorFlow project where 'targets' is defined as: 

`targets = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.int32, name='targets')`

Now saving my model with `saver.save(sess, model_path, meta_graph_suffix='meta', write_meta_graph=True)` gives me the following error:

`WARNING:tensorflow:Error encountered when serializing targets.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef.
'SparseTensor' object has no attribute 'name'`

I believe the warning is printed in the following lines of code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f974e8d0c2420c6f7e2a2791febb4781a266823f/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py#L1452

Reloading the model with `saver.restore(session, save_path)` seems to work though.

**Has anyone seen this issue before? Why would serializing a SparseTensor give that warning? Is there any way to avoid this warning?**

*I'm using TensorFlow version 0.10.0rc0 python 2.7 GPU version. I can't provide a minimal example, it doesn't happen all the time, only in certain configurations. And I can't share the model I currently have this issue with.*

Comment: why would you want to store a placeholder? - They are generally used for your inputs, and do not define the model, which is what you normally want to save.

Comment: @cleros : because in the end I want to restore the model from the meta-graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning means that a SparseTensor type of operation has been added to a collection whose to_proto() implementation expects a "name" field.

I'd consider this a bug if you intend to restore the complete graph from meta_graph, including all the Python objects, and you should find out which operation added that SparseTensor into a collection.

If you never intend to restore from meta_graph, then you can ignore this error.

Hope that helps.

Sherry

Comment: I intend to restore from the meta-graph eventually. Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it.

Comment: Fixed it by not adding the sparse tensors to collections.

Answer (score 3):

The component placeholders (for `indices`, `values`, and possibly `shape`) somehow get added to some collections.  If you trace through the code in `saver.py`, you can see `ops.get_all_collection_keys()` being used.

This should be a benign warning.  I will forward to the team to see if something can be done to improve this handling.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into this.